# WCF token authentication call from client without editing the existing service client calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have already made project which is using wcf service. Now I want to change my wcf service and want to use token authentication. but the problem is here I have to add credential for all the client calls. like this.

```
CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username@example.com";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "SomePassword";
```

but issue is that It is impossible for me to pass the credentials for all the service call from client. because there are around 100s of calls. So is there any possible way to set configuration in webconfig or if it is possible to make some "interceptor" for http call where we can send these credentials. please help regarding this. FYI, I am using asp.net webforms as client application. please give me help in asp.net webforms.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: You can have a method that return a new CalculatorClient. already configured.. You can have an configurator where you pass your client and it set everything. You can use WCF behavior and extent the client with the same mechanic. The last one will allow you to have credential in the application config.

Comment: You can see if using X509 certificate verification can meet your needs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/x-509-certificate-validator